# Некорректное получение директории

Tags: c#, .net, citrix

Есть диалоговое окно с выбором файла. Только после выбора файла путь до папки с ним записывается в глобальную статическую переменную.

```
using (var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName.ToUpper();

    Form1.CurrentPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName) + "\\";
}
```

И после этого создаётся объект, который использует эту переменную для получения файла в эту папку.

При локальном запуске программы путь получается корректно и всё работает нормально, все файлы записываются туда же, откуда был получен исходный файл.

При работе же с программой через citrix, полученный файл может упасть в папку, откуда был открыт исходный файл, а может пытаться положить его в папку с exe'шником и естественно вылетает исключение "Не хватает прав на запись в эту папку" и теряются полученные данные.

Сама переменная Form1.CurrentPath задаётся и меняется только при открытии нового файла. Объект для получения файла-ответа создаётся только в момент первого открытия файла для получения ключа сессии. При последующих открытиях файлов меняется только его поле `requestManager.downloadPath = Form1.CurrentPath;`

С чем может быть связано такое поведение программы? Посоветуйте как отловить в какой момент вообще может поменяться путь до открытого файла.

Comment: [Этот комментарий](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357457/select-file-in-client-when-use-citrix-server-in-c-sharp-winform#comment43169274_27357457) не поможет?

Comment: Вряд ли. И тут я с ними соглашусь. Зачем захламлять машину с приложениями ненужным мусором? Эти файлы должны оставаться на компах пользователей. Вопрос только в том почему иногда программа пытается сохранить их не там, где должна...

Comment: 1. Я бы тебе посоветовал для начала не связывать глобальную переменную с формой, а создать отдельный статичный класс с такими переменными. Что происходит с этой формой в процессе работы программы неизвестно - переинициализируется она, открывается, закрывается, соответственно и отследить изменение этой переменной будет не так просто.
2. Приложите кусок кода, где происходит обращение к requestManager.downloadPath = Form1.CurrentPath;. И в какой момент вызывается это событие.